# Exchange limit and expectation

Tags: limits, probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value, solution-verification

I'm trying to solving the following exercise and **I need a check on my reasoning**

> Let $X \geq0$ a.s. and $t>0$.
>
> Then $$\lim_{a \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{at} \frac{a^n}{n!} E[X^n e^{-aX}] = E\left[\lim_{a \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{at} \frac{(aX)^n}{n!} e^{-aX}\right].$$

---

Of course what I need to do is just to take the limit inside the expectation.

First, I notice that the limit is w.r.t $a$. Since I have a sum of *positive terms*, I want to apply the *monotone convergence theorem*.

First, before taking the limit, I bring the sum inside the expectation. $$\lim_{a \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{at} \frac{a^n}{n!} E[X^n e^{-aX}] = \lim_{a \rightarrow \infty} E[\sum_{n=1}^{at} \frac{a^n}{n!} E[X^n e^{-aX}]$$

My **question** is: to which sequence of functions do I apply the monotone convergence theorem?

I would say to the following one:

$$g(a)=\sum_{n=1}^{at} \frac{(aX)^n}{n!}e^{-aX}$$

(I just considered every term depending on $a$).

Since $g(a)$ is the partial sum of positive terms, it's obviously increasing (and obviously positive).

So I can take the limit inside the expectation by the *monotone convergence theorem*

Is this the way or am I missing something?

Comment: $at$ need not be an integer - you probably should put $\lfloor at\rfloor$ in the bounds for the sums.

Comment: @Math1000 You're right. Except for this, is evertything fine? I think it should be okay no.

Comment: * It should be okay now